# show status after post and keep entered model as is on MVC view

Tags: post, model-view-controller, status

I have this mvc controller that add a customer to the database called CustomerController. This Controller has one ActionResult called Add. It works as it is but I want to display a status message after the user hit submit, and I want all information added to the model be kept on the page as is. How can I keep the all the entered text in the form fields and also show a status message after the form has been posted?

```
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        // This is the empty view the user see when he is about to add new form data
        return View(new CreateSupplierViewModel());
    }

    public ActionResult AddNew(CreateSupplierViewModel model)
    {
        // I post to this and need to display the status of this on the view with the entered text fields as is
        return RedirectToAction("Add", "Supplier");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code as below :

The CustomerController :

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View(new CreateSupplierViewModel());
}
public ActionResult Add(CreateSupplierViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult AddNew(CreateSupplierViewModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Add", "Supplier", model);
}
```

Your SupplierController

```
public ActionResult Add(CreateSupplierViewModel model)
{

    //save the entity


    Viewbag.Message ="submit result";
    return RedirectToAction("Add", "Customer", model);
}
```

The Customer/Add.cshtml (show the submit result in view)

```
@if( Viewbag.Message != null)
 {
     <p> @Viewbag.Message </p>
 }
```